# Create Unlimited DataFrames from other DataFrame Column Category with Time-Series Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dictionary

I have three columns in a Time series.

The Time series is hourly and the index value.

I have multiple categories that are being measured hourly.

I have arbitrary lists of levels: these are usually odd names and I may pull anywhere between 40 to 40000 at a time.

I also have their varying values: for score 0 - 100.

So:

I want to make each Level have its own DataFrame:

(FULL DataFrame):

```
df = 

              date    levels    score
2019-01-01 00:00:00    1005  99.438851
2019-01-01 01:00:00    1005  92.081975
2019-01-01 02:00:00    1005  93.032991
2019-01-01 03:00:00    1005   1.991615
2019-01-01 04:00:00    1005  12.723531
2019-01-01 05:00:00    1005  74.443313
```

(One of hundreds of individual DataFrames I want generated, but NOT in a DICT)

```
df_is_1005 = 

              date      score
2019-01-01 00:00:00  99.438851
2019-01-01 01:00:00  92.081975
2019-01-01 02:00:00  93.032991
2019-01-01 03:00:00   1.991615
2019-01-01 04:00:00  12.723531
2019-01-01 05:00:00  74.443313
```

.... but for ALL THE LEVELS
.

And 
I have a bit of a problem!

I've done quite a lot of digging and have tried making a dict of the dataframes. How do I extract each of these?

Also, how do I name them individually as: df_of_{levels}?

This is the Time Series data I'll create for a toy model. (BUT there should be multiple datetime for each and every level, unlike here)

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='3/30/2019', freq='H')

df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])

df['level'] = np.random.randint(1000,1033,size=(len(date_rng)))

df['score'] = np.random.uniform(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
```

Keep in mind, the levels I may deal with could be hundreds and they are named bizarre things.

I'll have the time stamps for each of these as separate rows.

My desired goal is the have each of the possible levels, which there may well be more than just the small number here, to dynamically create dataframes.

NOW: I know I can create a Dictionary of dataframes.

BUT How do I extract each of dataframes with INDIVIDUAL Numbers?

I want, for example

```py
df = 

              date    levels    score
2019-01-01 00:00:00    1005  99.438851
2019-01-01 01:00:00    1005  92.081975
2019-01-01 02:00:00    1005  93.032991
2019-01-01 03:00:00    1005   1.991615
2019-01-01 04:00:00    1005  12.723531
2019-01-01 05:00:00    1005  74.443313
2019-01-01 06:00:00    1005  12.154499
2019-01-01 07:00:00    1005  96.439228
2019-01-01 08:00:00    1005  64.283731
2019-01-01 09:00:00    1005  83.165093
2019-01-01 10:00:00    1005  75.740610
2019-01-01 11:00:00    1005  25.721404
2019-01-01 12:00:00    1005  37.493829
2019-01-01 13:00:00    1005  51.783549
2019-01-01 14:00:00    1005   7.223582
2019-01-01 15:00:00    1005   0.932651
2019-01-01 16:00:00    1005  95.916686
2019-01-01 17:00:00    1005  11.579450
```

and same df, far later... :

```py
               date   levels      score
2019-01-01 00:00:00    1027  99.438851
2019-01-01 01:00:00    1027  92.081975
2019-01-01 02:00:00    1027  93.032991
2019-01-01 03:00:00    1027   1.991615
2019-01-01 04:00:00    1027  12.723531
2019-01-01 05:00:00    1027  74.443313
2019-01-01 06:00:00    1027  12.154499
2019-01-01 07:00:00    1027  96.439228
2019-01-01 08:00:00    1027  64.283731
2019-01-01 09:00:00    1027  83.165093
2019-01-01 10:00:00    1027  75.740610
2019-01-01 11:00:00    1027  25.721404
2019-01-01 12:00:00    1027  37.493829
2019-01-01 13:00:00    1027  51.783549
2019-01-01 14:00:00    1027   7.223582
2019-01-01 15:00:00    1027   0.932651
2019-01-01 16:00:00    1027  95.916686
2019-01-01 17:00:00    1027  11.579450
2019-01-01 18:00:00    1027  91.226938
2019-01-01 19:00:00    1027  31.564530
2019-01-01 20:00:00    1027  39.511358
2019-01-01 21:00:00    1027  59.787468
2019-01-01 22:00:00    1027   4.666549
2019-01-01 23:00:00    1027  92.197337
```

...etcetera...

EACH level individually, whatever it may be called (and there may be hundreds of them with random values):

To be converted to

df_{level_value_generated} =

```py
        date           score
2019-01-01 00:00:00   8.040233
2019-01-01 01:00:00  55.736688
2019-01-01 02:00:00  37.910143
2019-01-01 03:00:00  22.907763
2019-01-01 04:00:00   4.586205
2019-01-01 05:00:00  88.090652
2019-01-01 06:00:00  50.474533
2019-01-01 07:00:00  92.890208
2019-01-01 08:00:00  70.949978
2019-01-01 09:00:00  23.191488
2019-01-01 10:00:00  60.506870
2019-01-01 11:00:00  25.689149
2019-01-01 12:00:00  49.234296
2019-01-01 13:00:00  65.369771
2019-01-01 14:00:00  55.550065
2019-01-01 15:00:00  35.112297
2019-01-01 16:00:00  45.989587
2019-01-01 17:00:00  76.829787
2019-01-01 18:00:00   5.982378
2019-01-01 19:00:00  83.603115
2019-01-01 20:00:00   5.995648
2019-01-01 21:00:00  95.658097
2019-01-01 22:00:00  21.877945
2019-01-01 23:00:00  30.428798
2019-01-02 00:00:00  72.450284
2019-01-02 01:00:00  91.947018
2019-01-02 02:00:00  66.741502
2019-01-02 03:00:00  77.535416
2019-01-02 04:00:00  29.624868
2019-01-02 05:00:00  89.652003
```

So I can then list the  these DataFrames that are created DYNAMICALLY.

From here, I'd like to add them to a dictionary, the reason being, is that I want to train a Time-Series model to on each and every one of the individual DataFrames so I can have a different model for each of them, each with their own training and outputs.

If possibly, can I train multiple DataFrames from inside a dictionary individually?

If I just do a pivot table or groupby, I will have a large Dataframe that I'll have to individually call out columns of to train on the time series. So I'd rather not do that.

So, how do I dynamically create:

Newly named DataFrames from levels that are not all known in value,

each named:

df_{level_name}:

### DateTime Column:            Score_Column:

some dates...                scores 0-100

that will then drop the 'level_name' column in their own DataFrame, so that I can have as many dataframes as necessary, each named uniquely, programmatically, so I can then take each of these and then plug them into a new model or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem correctly, a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) should do exactly what you want.

To do this on your dataframe:

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['levels', 'date'], inplace=True)

# in the case of your example above, this will produce:
df = 

levels date                     score
1005   2019-01-01 00:00:00      99.438851
       2019-01-01 01:00:00      92.081975
       2019-01-01 02:00:00      93.032991
       2019-01-01 03:00:00      1.991615
       2019-01-01 04:00:00      12.723531
       2019-01-01 05:00:00      74.443313
       2019-01-01 06:00:00      12.154499
       2019-01-01 07:00:00      96.439228
       2019-01-01 08:00:00      64.283731
       2019-01-01 09:00:00      83.165093
       2019-01-01 10:00:00      75.740610
       2019-01-01 11:00:00      25.721404
       2019-01-01 12:00:00      37.493829
       2019-01-01 13:00:00      51.783549
       2019-01-01 14:00:00      7.223582
       2019-01-01 15:00:00      0.932651
       2019-01-01 16:00:00      95.916686
       2019-01-01 17:00:00      11.579450
1027   2019-01-01 00:00:00      99.438851
       2019-01-01 01:00:00      92.081975
       2019-01-01 02:00:00      93.032991
       2019-01-01 03:00:00      1.991615
       2019-01-01 04:00:00      12.723531
       2019-01-01 05:00:00      74.443313
       2019-01-01 06:00:00      12.154499
       2019-01-01 07:00:00      96.439228
       2019-01-01 08:00:00      64.283731
       2019-01-01 09:00:00      83.165093
       2019-01-01 10:00:00      75.740610
       2019-01-01 11:00:00      25.721404
       2019-01-01 12:00:00      37.493829
       2019-01-01 13:00:00      51.783549
       2019-01-01 14:00:00      7.223582
       2019-01-01 15:00:00      0.932651
       2019-01-01 16:00:00      95.916686
       2019-01-01 17:00:00      11.579450
       2019-01-01 18:00:00      91.226938
       2019-01-01 19:00:00      31.564530
       2019-01-01 20:00:00      39.511358
       2019-01-01 21:00:00      59.787468
       2019-01-01 22:00:00      4.666549
       2019-01-01 23:00:00      92.197337
#... etc
```

You can then access each level of the data using these indices:

```py
df.loc[1005, :]

  > 
date                     score
2019-01-01 00:00:00      99.438851
2019-01-01 01:00:00      92.081975
2019-01-01 02:00:00      93.032991
2019-01-01 03:00:00      1.991615
2019-01-01 04:00:00      12.723531
2019-01-01 05:00:00      74.443313
2019-01-01 06:00:00      12.154499
2019-01-01 07:00:00      96.439228
2019-01-01 08:00:00      64.283731
2019-01-01 09:00:00      83.165093
2019-01-01 10:00:00      75.740610
2019-01-01 11:00:00      25.721404
2019-01-01 12:00:00      37.493829
2019-01-01 13:00:00      51.783549
2019-01-01 14:00:00      7.223582
2019-01-01 15:00:00      0.932651
2019-01-01 16:00:00      95.916686
2019-01-01 17:00:00      11.579450
```

You can also loop through all the 'levels' of the data using:

```py
for level, data in df.groupby(level=0):
   # do something to 'level'
```

And, if needed, get a list of all 'levels' contained in the data:

```py
df.index.levels[0]

  > [1005, 1027, ...]
```

This might prove to be more flexible than creating numerous individually named dataframes, and is closer to the indended use of pandas.